# ¿Cómo puedo ponerle sombreado a un jframe this.setUndecorated(true);? - Java

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, apache-netbeans

pues eso, necesito colocarle a mi `JFrame` que está sin decorar, el borde sombreado. Si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradecería!

Pd: Tengo el  `this.setUndecorated(true);` porque tengo la cabecera del `JFrame` junto con los botones cerrar y minimizar personalizados a mi gusto.

Ejemplo de cómo quiero el sombreado:

[image: Imagen-sombra-ventana]

Comment: mmmmmm.....segun yo se eso no tiene nada que ver con el jFrame sino es una configuracion del windows manager, esto se puede activar y desactivar desde las configuraciones del sistema Operativo.

Comment: No sé si entendiste la pregunta... pero te la escribo más detalladamente. Resulta que estoy haciendo un pequeño programa en java con swing, le quité la decoración del frame (ventana) con this.setUndecorated(true); pero al quitar la decoración del frame (barra del título y botones) me quita también el sombreado del borde de la ventana. Entonces, lo que quiero hacer es darle sombra al borde....

Comment: Mmmmm .....puede que no se la mejor opción pero puedes poner al background del JFrame un color que de ese sombreado y encima un JPanel dejando un pequeño espacio para q se vea como sombra , para que puedas ajustarlo bien usa un layout absoluto.

Comment: @CristianManuelAbalos Esto es mas complejo que eso. La sombra del sistema operativo es un gradiente y contiene esquinas redondeadas. El gradiente comienza oscuro y luego se vuelve mas transparente. También se debe poder agregar un borde como en la imagen, es decir, tiene un borde negro de la ventana, y ademas incluye la sombra. Un desafió bastante divertido para hacer.

Comment: @JFrame, y agrégale que es un gradiente con transparencia.

Comment: @Sal No entiendo, ¿Cómo hago eso?

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres lograr esto, tienes que comprobar que el sistema operativo soporta decoraciones de ventanas con transparencia antes de mostrar el JFrame.

Segundo, deberías crear un borde personalizado que simule una sombra.

Para el primer paso, me base en el ejemplo de Oracle donde hacen una ventana con forma circular y transparencia. [ShapedWindowDemo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/ShapedWindowDemoProject/src/misc/ShapedWindowDemo.java)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphicsEnvironment gEnvironment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gDevice = gEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice();

    boolean isTranslucencySupported = 
        gDevice.isWindowTranslucencySupported(WindowTranslucency.TRANSLUCENT);

    /*
     * Si las ventanas con transparencia no están soportadas
     * en este sistema operativo, se debería cerrar todo.
     */
    if(!isTranslucencySupported) {
        System.out.println("Transparent windows are not supported");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        View view = new View();
        view.show();
    });
}
```

Para el segundo paso, me he basado en la siguiente [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26417276/17048239), donde hacen un JPanel con un gradiente creado con un bucle `for` y descontando la transparencia del color a medida que se va acercando hasta el final.

Esa idea esta buena, pero para esta respuesta he decidido crear un `Border` personalizado, ademas de que requería hacerle algunos cambios para poder personalizarlo mejor.

```
public class BorderShadow implements Border {

    private Color shadowColor;
    private int borderThickness;

    public BorderShadow(Color shadowColor, int borderThickness) {
        this.shadowColor = shadowColor;
        this.borderThickness = borderThickness;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        int red = shadowColor.getRed(), 
        green = shadowColor.getGreen(), 
        blue = shadowColor.getBlue();

        int cornerPadding = 60;
        int arcSize = 100 - cornerPadding;

        for(int i = 0; i < borderThickness; i++) {
            g2.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue, ((borderThickness / borderThickness) * i)));

            int rectWidth = width - ((i * 2) + 1);
            int rectHeight = height - ((i * 2) + 1);
            
            g2.drawRoundRect(i, i, rectWidth, rectHeight, arcSize, arcSize);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return new Insets(borderThickness, borderThickness, borderThickness, borderThickness);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Se dibuja un rectángulo con esquinas redondeadas al rededor de la ventana. Deben tener el redondeo para que el gradiente no se vea cuadrado como si lo dibujáramos con `drawRect`. Si te fijas en tu imagen, la sombra tiene las esquinas redondeas.

Ahora, como la sombra tendrá esquinas redondeadas, tienes que decidir de cuanto sera ese radio. Por defecto inicia en 100, esto creara una circunferencia que cruzara desde los 4 vértices de la ventana.

Como puedes ver en la siguiente imagen, las esquinas quedan excluidas de la sombra, si solo se utiliza un radio de 100 (cornerPadding 0).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para evitar esto, y que sea lo mas preciso a una sombra real, he creado la variable `cornerPadding`. Esta variable se encarga de expandir el diámetro horizontal y vertical, haciendo que la circunferencia ahora sea un poco mas grande.

De esa manera, en vez de terminar exactamente en todas las esquinas, toma las mismas medidas y las expande un poco mas, haciendo que el circulo se dibuje pasando las esquinas. Eso mostrara un sombra mas expandida, y parece que las esquinas son mas redondas como en la imagen que has pasado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede apreciar mas la diferencia si abres las imágenes en diferentes pestañas del navegador diferentes y vas cambiando.

---

Ahora, heredamos de `JFrame` para extender la funcionalidad, en este caso es mas para agregar una configuración por defecto. Esta configuración agrega los bordes y hace que la ventana sea `undecorated` por defecto, si no se hace así, lanzara un error al estar trabajando con transparencias.

Se agrega un borde de color Negro como en la imagen que tu has pasado, y ademas de esto, se agrega una sombra de color Azul. Esto se puede ver en las imágenes que ya he pasado.

```
class AppFrame extends JFrame {

    public AppFrame() {
        setUndecorated(true);

        setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

        Border outsideBorder = new BorderShadow(Color.BLUE, 20);
        Border insideBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1);
        
        getRootPane().setBorder(new CompoundBorder(outsideBorder, insideBorder));
    }

}
```

El `setBackground` es necesario para hacer que la VENTANA como tal, sea transparente. Si se agrega la sombra sin establecer el color de fondo transparente, tendrás una ventana de color blanco, y una sombra transparente haciendo ver el color blanco de la ventana en el fondo. Mira la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto, no se lo saques.

Por cierto, la sombra que aparece afuera del rectángulo es la del sistema operativo, en Ubuntu, aunque no tengas decoraciones de ventana aparece un sombra igual, debes contar solo la sombra azul.

Para que no aparezca como en las otras imágenes tienes que dejar el `background` transparente como dije. En Windows simplemente creara una sombra si no existe. En Linux, quitara la sombra del sistema y creara la simulada como en las imagenes.

---

Por ultimo y lo mas fácil, crear una ventana. Aquí puedes extender de AppFrame o como me gusta a mi, instanciar e ir agregando las cosas.

Lo mas importante es que no crees tu vista desde la misma clase de AppFrame, ya que estarías perdiendo la capacidad de crear varias ventanas con el mismo diseño. Esto trata de ser reutilizable. Hereda desde otra clase, o instancia como en mi ejemplo.

```
class View {

    private AppFrame frame;

    private JPanel centerPanel;
    private JLabel centerPanel_label;

    public View() {
        frame = new AppFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Test");
        frame.setSize(350, 350);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        createCenterPanel();
        frame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
        loadCloseEvent();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void loadCloseEvent() {
        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createCenterPanel() {
        centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        centerPanel_label = new JLabel("Click to close.");
        centerPanel.add(centerPanel_label);

        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void show() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

---

También en `AppFrame`, como parte de la configuración por defecto tendrías que sobrescribir los dos métodos `setSize` para sumarle el tamaño del borde.
Es decir, cuando creas una ventana de 500x500 el borde sacara parte de esos 500 para dibujarse a si mismo. Por lo tanto, si suponemos que la sombra viene del "sistema operativo" (en este caso es simulada), deberías sumarle el borde para que la "ventana" sea realmente de 500x500.
Considera "ventana" como el área donde se pueden agregar componentes, El borde ya que no se pueden agregar componentes.

Comment: Amigo el View que está a lo último del método main me lo muestra como error de sintaxis.

Comment: @Jonathan Si, fue un error mio, en el momento de escribir esto, lo hice con clases internas. Si has copiado el código en clases individuales, asegúrate de agregar `public class View` y `public class AppFrame`. En otras palabras asegúrate de que las clases se pueden acceder desde fuera agregando `public` al principio de estas.

Comment: Hice lo que me dices pero sigue dando error de sintaxis.

Comment: @Jonathan La clase View puede generar conflicto al importarla, cámbiale el nombre o asegurate de que estas importando la clase View que he creado y no la clase javax.swing.text;